# Why and when use .target in JS

Tags: javascript, dom-events

```
function listenColor(evt) {
  const target = evt.target || evt.srcElement; // get current input
  changeColor(target.value); // pass it's value to a changeColor function
}
```

Why and when we use target and why in this code `|| evt.srcElement`?

Comment: See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event - *"`Event.srcElement` A non-standard alias (from old versions of Microsoft Internet Explorer) for Event.target, which is starting to be supported in some other browsers for web compatibility purposes."*

Comment: `Event.target` is the actual target of the event, ex. when clicking on a button, the button is assigned to `.target`. This makes possible ex. to listen all clicks on a table by a single event, instead of attaching an event listener to all cells or rows on the table.

Comment: I hope you find my answer below helpful.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a thorough brief:

> why and when we use target and why in this code "||evt.srcElement". thanks

`event.target` is used to identify and get the element that triggered the event. `event.srcElement` does the same thing but it's Internet Explorer compatible. So they're used with an `OR` =  `||` just in case the other didn't work.

So both `event.target` and `event.srcElement` returns the Javascript Element Object of the element that triggered the event.

Consider the use case below:

Imagine you had 4 links below:

```
<a class="link" href="/link1"></a>
<a class="link" href="/link2"></a>
<a class="link" href="/link3"></a>
<a class="link" href="/link4"></a>
```

And you want to get the `href` of the element to use to change `window.location`:

You might think of using `e = document.querySelector(".link")` to get the object of the element that triggered the event. But this won't work because you have 4 links with the same query selector. so to fix this you'd want to get the `e = event.target || event.srcElement`, this returns the actual element that triggered the event and by calling `.getAttribute("href")` you will get the `href` of the element that triggered the `event`.